# "by" versus "by the time before"

Tags: prepositions

The examination will start on the 20th.

You can contact any day before the 10th.

Now:

> In the case of not getting the Registration card, contact the office
> ten days before the commencement of the examination; otherwise, the
> candidate will solely be responsible.

Is the use of 'ten days before the commencement' ok here? Or it should be:

> ...contact the office by the time ten days before the commencement of
> the examination...

Note: The last date for contacting the office is the 10th.

Comment: I don't think *You can claim this by the 10th of the month* is natural English. Certainly, ***I*** don't understand what it's supposed to mean. Does it imply you *can't* claim something *until* the 10th? Or that you can only claim it *up until* the 10th? It's very confusing, to me.

Comment: @ FumbleFingers  The questions edited.

Comment: _By the time ten days_ is not idiomatic. I would suggest _up to ten days before_, otherwise it suggests that you have to wait until 10th!

Comment: Your first sentence doesn't have "by" in it. I tried to update your title, but I don't think it's accurate.

Comment: What @KateBunting said. *[If you didn't receive the Registration card], contact the office **up to*** (or ***no later than***) *ten days before the commencement of the examination*. Note that in this exact context, ***up to*** might be a little confusing even for native speakers (because 11 days before is "early enough", and 9 days before is too late, but we generally measure such "restricted validity" time periods from ***after*** some crucial date, not ***before***, so you have to pay attention). ***No later than*** doesn't cause any such confusion.